# Checking for criteria within a deep nested list

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using MongoDB and PyMongo and have the below data structure.

```
[
    {
        "position": 367,
        "entropy": 0.1327801096975522,
        "variants_flattened": [
            "GFRHQNSEG",
            "GFRHQNSEG",
            "GFRHQNSEG",
            "GFRHQNAEG"
        ],
        "supports": 51,
        "sequences": [
            {
                "position": 367,
                "sequence": "GFRHQNSEG",
                "count": 50,
                "conservation": 98.03921568627452,
                "motif_short": "I",
                "motif_long": "Index",
                "id": [
                    "APQ31289.1",
                    "ASU55526.1",
                    "ASU55528.1",
                    "APQ31291.1"
                ],
                "strain": [
                    "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s200/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/164/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/1185/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s228/2016"
                ],
                "country": [
                    "HA Hemagglutinin",
                    "HA Hemagglutinin",
                    "HA Hemagglutinin",
                    "HA Hemagglutinin"
                ],
                "host": [
                    "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s200/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/164/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/1185/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s228/2016"
                ]
            },
            {
                "position": 367,
                "sequence": "GFRHQNAEG",
                "count": 1,
                "conservation": 1.9607843137254902,
                "motif_short": "Ma",
                "motif_long": "Major",
                "id": [
                    "QBM69728.1"
                ],
                "strain": [
                    "Influenza A virus A/China/70793/2016"
                ],
                "country": [
                    "HA Hemagglutinin"
                ],
                "host": [
                    "Influenza A virus A/China/70793/2016"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "variants": 2
    }
]
```

The root level list contains multiple objects of similar structure.

What I need is to get the instances (the specific object from the "sequences" list only) where "motif_short" is equal to "I".

The expected output is (in this  particular example, there is only one output object, but there can be multiple objects that match this criteria within a single instance):

```
{
                "position": 367,
                "sequence": "GFRHQNSEG",
                "count": 50,
                "conservation": 98.03921568627452,
                "motif_short": "I",
                "motif_long": "Index",
                "id": [
                    "APQ31289.1",
                    "ASU55526.1",
                    "ASU55528.1",
                    "APQ31291.1"
                ],
                "strain": [
                    "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s200/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/164/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/1185/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s228/2016"
                ],
                "country": [
                    "HA Hemagglutinin",
                    "HA Hemagglutinin",
                    "HA Hemagglutinin",
                    "HA Hemagglutinin"
                ],
                "host": [
                    "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s200/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/164/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/1185/2016",
                    "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s228/2016"
                ]
}
```

I am quite new to MongoDB and have tried a few options such as Aggregate, but I  am right where I started. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add the exact output required as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem with aggregate `$project` and `$filter`. Please try the following script for this specific problem:

```
#if col is our collection object in pymongo

result = col.aggregate([{'$project': {'sequences': { '$filter': { 'input': '$sequences', 'as': 's', 'cond': { '$eq': ['$$s.motif_short', 'I'] } } } }}])
```

This query projects on sequences and filters on motif_short equals "I". You will get something like this as result:

```
{
  "_id":"xyz",
  "sequences":[
    {
      "position":367,
      "sequence":"GFRHQNSEG",
      "count":50,
      "conservation":98.03921568627452,
      "motif_short":"I",
      "motif_long":"Index",
      "id":[
        "APQ31289.1",
        "ASU55526.1",
        "ASU55528.1",
        "APQ31291.1"
      ],
      "strain":[
        "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s200/2016",
        "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/164/2016",
        "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/1185/2016",
        "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s228/2016"
      ],
      "country":[
        "HA Hemagglutinin",
        "HA Hemagglutinin",
        "HA Hemagglutinin",
        "HA Hemagglutinin"
      ],
      "host":[
        "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s200/2016",
        "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/164/2016",
        "Influenza A virus A/Shandong-Zhifu/1185/2016",
        "Influenza A virus A/Xiamen/s228/2016"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```